# db.Query.fetch(limit) returning all results instead of limit

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using appengine on python 2.7 and I'm querying a database Entity with the following call:

```
query = Model.all().filter("profile =", p_key)
query.order('-created')
query.run(limit=10)
logging.debug('count is %i' % query.count()) #shows 35 instead of 10
```

I've also tried using query.fetch(10) but still returns all results instead of limit. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are not updating the `query` variable.

do this:

```
query = Model.all().filter("profile =", p_key)
query = query.order('-created')
query = query.run(limit=10)
```

now the result is assigned to your `query` variable.
you were querying but not assigning it to anything.

Comment: That's odd.  The use of all() and run() suggests this is using the old db package, where order() has a side effect on the query, and the assignment is not needed; moreover run() returns an iterator which is a completely different object than a query.  The real problem is that run(limit=N) doesn't store the limit on the query; you would have to call q.count(limit=N) to apply the limit to the count call.  Maybe you could post the actual code that worked for you?

Comment: @GuidovanRossum if `run()` returns an iterator what is the problem of assigning that iterator to a variable. ok i agree that naming it `query` and assigning the iterator/result to that variable is not meaningful but besides that it's the solution to the problem. or am i missing something?

Comment: It's just the confusing name you gave it -- all the more confusing since the original code example then went on to call query.count(), which would definitely fail if query was an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Per the GAE [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass) - did you try

```
query.fetch(limit = 10)
```

also did you verify that your filter works (without any limit command) - here's the documentation on [filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_filter)